# How to migrate a DB in Postgres from one version to another using Sequelize?

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

What is the best way to migrate a DB in Postgres from one version to another using Sequelize. Also, , the migrate as a whole can be performed on the DB, and the whole thing can be undone if there is an error.

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem. Why use sequelize instead of {pg_dump+pg_restore}, or pg_upgrade ?

Comment: @wildplasser - We want to do this as part of a application upgrade and so need it to be scriptable. We are already using Sequelize for all the database operations and so would want to do it the same way.